# Vue 3 component data binding doesn't work

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

In the following example, `{{test}}` doesn't get updated according to the input of the component. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
<Component v-model="test"></Component>
{{test}}

<script type="module">
import {createApp} from './node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js';

const Component = {
    props: {
        modelValue: String,
    },
    emits: [
        'update:modelValue',
    ],
    template: `<input @keyup="updateValue">`,
    methods: {
        updateValue(event) {
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value);
        },
    },
};

const app = createApp({});
app.component('Component', Component);
app.mount('body');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When Vue 3 mounts, it replaces whole DOM node it is mounted on. `body` in your case. This is not ideal. Try to add surrounding `div` and mount on it instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to declare `test` variable in `data` options.

```
  const app = createApp({
    data: () => {
      return {
        test: ''
      }
    }
  });
```